# Why UnrecoverableKeyException Exception is thrown in this case?

Tags: java

I have a code where I access keystore. When my password is wrong I get an exception of type `UnrecoverableKeyException`. So I wrote my code as :

```
    try {
            InputStream f = new FileInputStream("<location to file>")
            keyStore.load( f , passwords );
        } catch(UnrecoverableKeyException e){
                 log.error("")

        }
```

But that doesn't catch the exception. So in my `catch` block, I changed my code to :

```
catch(Exception e)
{
  log.error(e.getClass(),e)
}
```

which catch the exception and prints the class type is of `class java.io.IOException`. But why does in the first place I get an message that exception is of `UnrecoverableKeyException`?

Whats happening actually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure something isn't unwrapping the exception? Can you show the stack trace from the UnrecoverableKeyException?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`KeyStore.load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,%20char%5b%5d%29) states that it can throw an `IOException`, and also:

> If the error is due to a wrong password, the cause of the IOException should be an UnrecoverableKeyException

This means what you catch is actually an `IOException` but `e.getCause()` would be an `UnrecoverableKeyException`. When the stack trace gets printed, you would see all causes in the chain, which perhaps led you to think it was an `UnrecoverableKeyException`.